# MongoDB Library for CodeIgniter (pecl mongodb, not mongo )

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I just install php mongodb driver by "pecl install mongodb", and the phpinfo page shows mongodb module, that means the module installed successfully, but when I use the code:

```
"if ( ! class_exists('Mongo') && ! class_exists('MongoClient'))
{
show_error("The MongoDB PECL extension has not been installed or enabled", 500);
}"
```

in the library file of codeigniter, it shows the error, then I guess maybe this is just for mongo, not for mongodb, so is there any codeingiter library for mongodb?

Comment: ok, I just turn back to php5.4, and mongodb3.0, and then use mongo library,

Comment: did you find any solution? even I'm facing the same problem with php7.0 and mongodb3.4

Comment: Please, I would like a solution too, same problem as austin rodrigues

Answer (score 4):

enable both

- extension=php_mongo.dll
- extension=php_mongodb.dll

in php.ini file